# Spark SQL data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data structure:

```
{"Emp":{"Name":"John", "Sal":"2000", "Address":[{"loc":"Sanjose","Zip":"222"},{"loc":"dayton","Zip":"333"}]}}
```

Now I want to load the data into a data frame and want to append zip to loc. The loc column name should be same (loc). The transformed data should be like this:

```
{"Emp":{"Name":"John", "Sal":"2000", "Address":[{"loc":"Sanjose222","Zip":"222"},{"loc":"dayton333","Zip":"333"}]}}
```

No RDDs. I need a data frame operation to achieve this, preferably with the `withColumn` function. How can I do this?

Comment: Please post what did you tried

Answer (score 0):

Given a data structure as

```
val jsonString = """{"Emp":{"Name":"John","Sal":"2000","Address":[{"loc":"Sanjose","Zip":"222"},{"loc":"dayton","Zip":"333"}]}}"""
```

You can covert it to dataframe as

```
val df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(jsonString::Nil))
```

which would give you

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Emp                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([222,Sanjose], [333,dayton]),John,2000]|
+-----------------------------------------------------+

//root
// |-- Emp: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Address: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- Zip: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- loc: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Sal: string (nullable = true)
```

Now to get the desired output you would need to *separate struct Emp column to separate columns* and *use Address array column in udf function to get your desired result* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def attachZipWithLoc = udf((array: Seq[Row])=> array.map(row => address(row.getAs[String]("loc")+row.getAs[String]("Zip"), row.getAs[String]("Zip"))))

df.select($"Emp.*")
  .withColumn("Address", attachZipWithLoc($"Address"))
  .select(struct($"Name".as("Name"), $"Sal".as("Sal"), $"Address".as("Address")).as("Emp"))
```

where `address` in `udf` class is a `case class`

```
case class address(loc: String, Zip: String)
```

which should give you

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Emp                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|[John,2000,WrappedArray([Sanjose222,222], [dayton333,333])]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

//root
// |-- Emp: struct (nullable = false)
// |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Sal: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Address: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- loc: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- Zip: string (nullable = true)
```

Now to get the *json* you can just use `.toJSON` and you should get

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Emp":{"Name":"John","Sal":"2000","Address":[{"loc":"Sanjose222","Zip":"222"},{"loc":"dayton333","Zip":"333"}]}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```